# Selecting form values in redux-from

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want to show form when click on radio button using redux-from, here is i following tutorial link, (implements using checkbox)
 [selectingformvalues](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/selectingformvalues/) but i cant implement it on radio button,

i have 2 radio button

radio button **x** click,  shows **a** form

radio button **y** click, shows **b** form and hide **a** form

```
    <label htmlFor="hasEmail">percentage</label>
    <div>
      <Field
        name="taxtype"
        component="input"
        type="radio"
        value="percentage"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label htmlFor="hasEmail">usd</label>
    <div>
      <Field
        name="taxtype"
        component="input"
        type="radio"
        value="usd"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  {usd && (
    <div>
      <label>Email</label>
      <div>
        <Field
          name="email"
          component="input"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"

        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )}

  {percentage && (
    <div>
      <label>Email 2</label>
      <div>
        <Field
          name="email"
          component="input"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"

        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )}



 const percentage = selector(state, 'percentage')
  const usd = selector(state, 'usd')
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: open different forms when i click radio button, form depends on radio button values

Comment: You have to provide us with some of your code that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example you referred you rewritten to include two radios

https://codesandbox.io/s/koz449qo6o

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need it in radio button because  , in checkbox we can select both that's is the problem

Comment: Did you try changing `type="checkbox"`to `type="radio"`?

Comment: yes, its; not working, because , radio button working bit different from checkbox

Comment: I updated the code, you can find a working version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/koz449qo6o